# Display an integer comma separated in C?

Tags: c

How can we display an integer comma separated in C?

For example if `int i=9876543`, result should be `9,876,543.`

Comment: The answers in "How to format a number from 1123456789 to 1,123,456,789 in C?" do not provide a portable answer or one that works for all `int`  (INT_MIN fails for many).  The accepted answer here is portable and works for INT_MIN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can play with `LC_NUMERIC` and `setlocale()` or build your own function, something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *fmt(long x)
{
    char s[64], *p = s, *q, *r;
    int len;

    len = sprintf(p, "%ld", x);
    q = r = malloc(len + (len / 3) + 1);
    if (r == NULL) return NULL;
    if (*p == '-') {
        *q++ = *p++;
        len--;
    }
    switch (len % 3) {
        do {
            *q++ = ',';
            case 0: *q++ = *p++;
            case 2: *q++ = *p++;
            case 1: *q++ = *p++;
        } while (*p);
    }
    *q = '\0';
    return r;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *s = fmt(9876543);

    printf("%s\n", s);
    free(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for Duff's device revisited!

Comment: +1 Have not found an answer that works for INT_MIN and is portable in "How to format a number from 1123456789 to 1,123,456,789 in C?".  This one appears to be both (aside form the magic number 64).

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no built-in function for that. However you can convert the integer to string and than compute the comma positions depending on the length of the resulting string(tip:first comma will be after `strlen(s)%3` digits, avoid leading comma).